# react native expo installed apk using eas not opens and closes suddenly

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, apk

i have created expo managed workflow project which works fine in expo go app but after downloading and installing apk file using eas build ,i am trying to open app but it shows splash screen and closes.can anyone explai why this is heppening?

this is my eas.json file:

```js
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.44.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk","gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      },"developmentClient": true
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: We have similar `eas.json` and I also can't make the app run when I install it on my device. Have you figured it out?

Comment: same issue, any solution?